# WebClient.DownloadData returns status code 444

Tags: c#, webclient, imagedownload

I'm trying to download images from a url but getting exception like "The remote server returned an error: (444) No Response."

here is the code for downloading images

```cs
string url = "https://listing-images.homejunction.com/bright/304545918990/photo_20.jpg";
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] byteUrl = wc.DownloadData(url);
    Image orgImg = Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(byteUrl));
    Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(orgImg);
    Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, orgImg.Width, orgImg.Height - CropSize), bmpImage.PixelFormat);
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    bmpCrop.Save(memoryStream, orgImg.RawFormat);
    return memoryStream;
}
```

Comment: 444 isn't a standard HTTP status code, so I would recommend consulting any API documentation you have, or contacting whoever runs homejunction.com to ask them about it.

Comment: The only thing I found is that it's used as an [unnoficial status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#nginx) by nginx: _"Used internally to instruct the server to return no information to the client and close the connection immediately."_

Comment: Error 444 is not a common error but indicates Connection Closed. You are opening a binary jpg file.  A Webclient (Uses HTTP with HTML format) will give an error when binary data is sent.  You either need to encode the binary to a base64 string or make the image a moime attachment.